# Python DataFrame: How to connect different columns with the same name and merge them into one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Problem

I have a df that has many columns with the same column name. I wish to use the same column name as a key to do like UNION in SQL.

### Example

see example data:

```
cie = ['y','n','y','n']
words = [['bank', 'payment'],['student', 'loan','payment'],['bank', 'payment'],['student', 'loan']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=words, index=cie)
```

df:

```
    0   1   2
y   bank    payment None
n   student loan    payment
y   bank    payment None
n   student loan    None
```

df.T:

```
    y       n       y       n
0   bank    student bank    student
1   payment loan    payment loan
2   None    payment None    None
```

I need to combine the two y columns since I want to calculate how many times the words in y leads to the results to be sure.
Ideally the results should be:

```
    y       n
0   bank    student
1   payment loan
2   None    payment
3   bank    student
4   payment loan
5   None    None
```

I tried many methods but they do not work. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC first `melt` , the using `cumcount` create the additional key , now you will see the problem became `pivot`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index')
s.variable=s.groupby('index').cumcount()
s.pivot(*s.columns).T
Out[43]: 
index           n        y
variable                  
0         student     bank
1         student     bank
2            loan  payment
3            loan  payment
4         payment     None
5            None     None
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, simple get the two columns and merge them, flatten them, do that for both columns, and construct a new dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'y':np.array(list(zip(*df.T['y'].values.tolist()))).flatten().tolist(),
                   'n': np.array(list(zip(*df.T['n'].values.tolist()))).flatten().tolist()})
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
         n        y
0  student     bank
1     loan  payment
2  payment     None
3  student     bank
4     loan  payment
5     None     None
```